# Input HTML mostrando resultado do PHP

Tags: php, html, input

Estou começando a brincar com PHP, e estou meio que bolando um sisteminha Web. O sistema seria mais ou menos uma ideia assim. O usuário preenche por exemplo, um código (ID), digamos 001212 num input do tipo texto e abaixo dele há um input do tipo texto que retorna o nome dele com base em uma consulta (por enquanto estou fazendo com IF, visto que não sei banco de dados ainda, só para brincar e simular).

Tentei algumas coisas aqui, como posso fazer?

Se precisarem do código, posso postar também.

Comment: Coloca o código sempre ajuda.

Comment: Coloque o código para termos uma ideia de como esta fazendo

Comment: vc já conseguiu fazer umas "coisas" e tal. Conseguiu postar e exibir na tela o que o usuário digitou. Pois bem, ok, então qual exatamente a dúvida? A pergunta, no segundo parágrafo, está muito vaga.

Comment: Olá Rodrigo, pelo que entendi você tem um formulário, nele você possui alguns campos e deseja que estes sejam atualizados com base no preenchimento de outros, por exemplo, ao preencher o ID ele informar no campo de nome o nome do produto. Se for isso você tem duas opções, uma usa AJAX e javascript, nessa você com javascript adiciona um listener no formulário e envia um pedido, recebe a resposta e via JS você adiciona ela no formulário, no outro você envia a página para o servidor e devolve o HTML com os campos já populados (com os atributos value dos inputs preenchidos), é mais o menos isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra você fazer isso, seria ideal usar `jQuery/Ajax`, pois ficaria mais dinâmico.
Seria algo mais ou menos assim no HTML:

```
    <html>
    <title>Meu site</title>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Id: <input type="text" name="id" /><br/>
    Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" /><br/><p>
    <button onclick="chamaId();">Conferir</button>
    </body>
   <script>
    function chamaId(){
    $.getJSON('usuarios.php', function(dataf) {
    id = $('input[name=id]').val();
    nome = dataf;
    if(!nome[id] == ""){
         $('input[name=nome]').val(nome[id]);
    } else  {
         $('input[name=nome]').val("ID "+id+" inexistente");
    }
    });
}
</script>
</html>
```

E no arquivo **usuarios.php**:

```
<?php 
$users = array("1220" => "Cassiano","9090" => "Maria","1522" => "Fulano", "001212" => "Rodrigo");
echo json_encode($users);
```

Uma explicação rápida porque estou meio ocupado: 
no arquivo "usuarios.php" eu criei uma `Array` como pode ver, cada ID de uma `array` (*a chave*) aponta para usuário (*valor*), a função `json_encode` converte essa array em formato `json`, após isso, a função `chamaId()` obtém o valor digitado na `input`, recebe os dados em `jSon` do arquivo `PHP` usando `$.getJSON`, e altera o valor da segunda `input` com a chave digitado na primeira `input`, 
Sei que a explicação está meia confusa, depois eu edito e explico melhor para você.
Aproveita o tempo livre pra dar uma estudada no código!
Boa sorte.

Comment: `async: false,` com `success: function(dados) {` não funciona, ou melhor dizendo, está errado ou melhor dizendo, não há necessidade de async:false com success. Outra coisa SJax é considerado ruim.

Comment: Ok, mudei para `$.getJSON`, desculpe minha inexperiência, nunca estudei jQuery, mas como ninguém ajudou o Rodrigo, então respondi mesmo assim.
Mas qualquer correção, por favor, sinta-se a vontade pra corrigir o código. obrigado!

Comment: Perfeito! Era algo nesse estilo que queria! Um colega havia me dito que teria que usar JS mesmo. Aos demais quê comentaram, obrigado igualmente!